# Adding an additional menu in Wordpress

Tags: menus

I am using wp_nav_menu() and I want to add the search box as a part of the menu.

I am having trouble figuring it out and was hoping for some assistance:

My code:

```
        <?php 
        $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false);
        wp_nav_menu( $args ); 
        ?>
```

Now I want to add an additional <li> element to the end or the menu <ul> and all I want in the <li> is the output of:

```
        <?php get_search_form();?>
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using wp_get_nav_menu_items() and got each item individually and then built the li manually as shown in this example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items#Examples

Answer (score 0):

b-grader

First, you should you this format to add menu location (in your function.php)

```
add_action('init', 'register_top_menu');

function register_top_menu() {
register_nav_menu('top_menu', __('Top Menu', 'your_text_domain'));
register_nav_menu('bottom_menu', __('Bottom Menu', 'your_text_domain'));
}
```

(note: 'your_text_domain' is used for translation..)

Then in the place you want the menu to apear..

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

so... if you want to add another item seperate to the menu its like this:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 700px; overflow:hidden;">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <?php get_search_form();?>
</div>
```

ofcourese i reccomend using the css at the style.css file
and using classes on the div's themselfs but thats the way
i would go about it..

That way you can control the look of each object without
them inefiring with each other..

Hope this helps.
Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: thanks but that ends the menu ul.li which I am using html5 & css to create rounded corners - the rounded corner now rounds out and then the search is presented.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <nav>
   <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
   <ul>
      <li><?php get_search_form();?></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Make nav > ul float left, style the li with your rounded corners and you are done... probably you would need to match the menu ul element margin-right to keep the same distance them. I've done this before and worked great.